# Can't get single \ in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn python, and I'm pretty new at it, and I can't figure this one part out.
Basically, what I'm doing now is something that takes the source code of a webpage, and takes out everything that isn't words.

Webpages have a lot of \n and \t, and I want something that will find \ and delete everything between it and the next ' '.

```
def removebackslash(source):
    while(source.find('\') != -1):
        startback = source.find('\')
        endback = source[startback:].find(' ') + startback + 1
        source = source[0:startback] + source[endback:]
    return source
```

is what I have. It doesn't work like this, because the `\'` doesn't close the string, but when I change `\` to `\\`, it interprets the string as `\\`. I can't figure out anything that is interpreted at `'\'`

Comment: That's because backslash should be escaped. Like this: `source.find('\\')`.

Comment: You believe that \n are 2 characters. They are not, it's only one, so you cannot skip everything between \ and n or r because they'd have to be 2 characters.

Comment: Btw watch for the code highlighting. In this case, it's wrong, because your source is wrong. Secondary indicators like this are useful for finding a bug without wasting too much time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`\` is an escape character; it either gives characters a special meaning or takes said special meaning away. Right now, it's escaping the closing single quote and treating it as a literal single quote. You need to escape it with itself to insert a literal backslash:

```
def removebackslash(source):
    while(source.find('\\') != -1):
        startback = source.find('\\')
        endback = source[startback:].find(' ') + startback + 1
        source = source[0:startback] + source[endback:]
    return source
```

Comment: This is what I read everywhere, but when I make this change is searches the source for '\\'.

Comment: I did try it. Then I even did it outside of the function, to see if the problem might lie somewhere else. When I print a source[source.find('\\'):] it starts with a \\. Every time.

"blahblahblah\andstuff".find('\\') evaluates to -1 for me.

Comment: @fnsjdnfksjdb: `"blahblahblah\andstuff".find("\\")` *should* evaluate to -1.  There's no single backslash in "blahblahblah\andstuff": there's only "\a", which is a single character (chr(7)). `"blahblahblah\\andstuff".find("\\")`, on the other hand, is 12.

Answer (score 7):

Try using replace:

```
str.replace(old, new[, count])
```

Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

So in your case:

```
my_text = my_text.replace('\n', '')
my_text = my_text.replace('\t', '')
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you need to use `'\\'`.  The reason you think this isn't working is because when you get the results, they look like they begin with two backslashes.  But they don't begin with two backslashes, it's just that Python *shows* two backslashes.  If it didn't, you couldn't tell the difference between a newline (represented as `\n`) and a backslash followed by the letter n (represented as `\\n`).

There are two ways to convince yourself of what's really going on.  One is to use print on the result, which causes it to expand the escapes:

```
>>> x = "here is a backslash \\ and here comes a newline \n this is on the next line"
>>> x
u'here is a backslash \\ and here comes a newline \n this is on the next line'
>>> print x
here is a backslash \ and here comes a newline 
 this is on the next line
>>> startback = x.find('\\')
>>> x[startback:]
u'\\ and here comes a newline \n this is on the next line'
>>> print x[startback:]
\ and here comes a newline 
 this is on the next line
```

Another way is to use `len` to verify the length of the string:

```
>>> x = "Backslash \\ !"
>>> startback = x.find('\\')
>>> x[startback:]
u'\\ !'
>>> print x[startback:]
\ !
>>> len(x[startback:])
3
```

Notice that `len(x[startback:])` is 3.  The string contains three characters: backslash, space, and exclamation point.  You can see what's going on even more simply by just looking at a string that contains only a backslash:

```
>>> x = "\\"
>>> x
u'\\'
>>> print x
\
>>> len(x)
1
```

`x` only looks like it starts with two backslashes when you evaluate it at the interactive prompt (or otherwise use it's `__repr__` method).  When you actually print it, you can see it's only one backslash, and when you look at its length, you can see it's only one character long.

So what this means is you need to escape the backslash in your `find`, and you need to recognize that the backslashes displayed in the output may also be doubled.

Answer (score 2):

The SO auto-format shows your problem.  Since `\` is used to escape characters, it's escaping the end quotes.  Try changing that line to (note the use of double quotes):

```
while(source.find("\\") != -1):
```

Read more about escape characters [in the docs.](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anyone's mentioned this yet, but if you don't want to deal with having to escape characters just use a raw string.

```
source.find(r'\')
```

Adding the letter *r* before the string tells Python not to interpret any special characters and keeps the string exactly as you type it.

Comment: It still escapes the end of the string, though.